# Winddk APIS: KeQueryActiveProcessors and KeQueryMaximumProcessorCountEx

Tags: windows, operating-system, x86, driver, wdk

I need to find number of logical processors on windows for Intel hw (I am writing a simple driver). I found two windows APIs. KeQueryActiveProcessors tells currently active processors. KeQueryMaximumProcessorCountEx tells the number of processors in all the groups. Can it ever happen that both the apis will return different numbers. In other words, will it ever happen that number of active processors will change during run time for windows.

Thanks, 
Abhijeet

Answer (score 1):

First, yes, the number of processors may change at run-time, see [Dynamic Hardware Partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544227%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Second, for Win7/2k8r2+, you should probably call [KeQueryGroupAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553007%28VS.85%29.aspx), which is the analogue to KeQueryActiveProcessors.